What is the definition of an n-tuple and what is the general cardinality? What's the cardinality of an infinite-tuple?
I recently learned about the Kazimierz Kuratowski definition of an ordered pair. I decided to make a problem set for my school's math club regarding the cardinality of these set definitions and how to define ordered triples and higher-ordered tuples.
Using $(a,b)_K=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. I expanded this to $(a,b,c)_K$ as $$(a,b,c)_K=(a,(b,c)_K)_K$$ $$=\{\{a\},\{a,(b,c)_K\}\}=\{\{a\},\{a,\{\{b\},\{b,c\}\}\}$$ and saw a chance to define an n-tuple with recursive sets. I'm quite an amateur enthusiast as I am only now taking linear algebra and have never taken a discrete math course, so I'm not sure I grasp what cardinality is in its entirety. Still, my question is whether the cardinality will always be two and if n-tuples can even be defined this way since I've seen people say that n-tuples are a completely different thing.
As far as I'm concerned right now cardinality seems to be the number of objects that are inside the outer brackets which looks like it's always two.
Additionally, I wanted to have fun and try to define $\infty$-tuples this way and claim their cardinality was two, but I was told I couldn't since the definition cannot be recalled infinitely. If there is a separate definition, please share. I would also like to know the reasoning behind why you can't expand Kazimierz Kuratowski's definition to infinity.
I'm aware that the number of distinct elements of the tuples will be whatever their order is, but I'm curious about how their definition of cardinality intersects with set-theoretic definitions of cardinality and whether it is cohesive or not.
I hope that this makes sense. Thanks to whoever tries to help.

There are standard definitions for tuples that you can find easily. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple carefully and then tell us if anything remains unclear.

These definitions of "ordered pair" and "n-tuple" should come with warning labels.
